# InvalidCast error when running Task<>

Tags: c#, .net, task

I am running into an issue where I have written a program to scrape internal websites for data. The currently run sequentially but as the time to do this is too great I now need to run them concurrently. I have started reading that running them as Tasks is the best way to do this. So sample code looks like this.

My scrape function returns a DataSet

```
Task<DataSet> task = new Task<DataSet>(() => Scraper.Website1(IE_Object, dataset));
task.Start();

DataSet web1_ds = task.Result;
```

When the function `Scraper.Website1()` runs it hits an InvalidCast exception when trying to type text into input fields.

this method works perfectly fine when not running as a Task. Where am I going wrong?

edit:

The error is occurring in the first _ie.TextField().TypeText();

```
if (!Globals.CheckLogin(_ie))
{
    CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.DEBUG, "Scraper: " + "Website1(): " + "Logging   Into Site");
    //enter login details
    _ie.TextField("_ctl0_dnnLOGIN_txtUsername").TypeText("username");
    _ie.TextField("_ctl0_dnnLOGIN_txtPassword").TypeText("password");
    _ie.Link("_ctl0_dnnLOGIN_btnLogin").Click();
    //confirm login
    _ie.WaitUntilContainsText("Logout");
    CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.DEBUG, "Scrappy: " + "Synnex(): " + "Logged In");
}
```

Comment: Where in the Scraper is it erroring? Post code.

Comment: hey i have updated with the code

Comment: is the scrapper class website1 method thread safe, try to implement lock and see if that resolves the problem

Comment: Hi Brijesh, implemented lock{} and still had the InvalidCast exception